# If I perform a linear transform on an input and output variable of a regression, and then want to "untransform" the coefficients, how do I do that?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, regression

I am running a regression, with X predicting Y. I have performed linear transforms on X and Y to put them on the same scale (did this to be able to fit priors for Bayesian parameter estimation).

If I want the resulting coefficients to be on the original scale, how do I untransform them?

Is it:

```
Coefficient * (slope of the transformation for X / slope of the transformation for Y)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Transform as $y=a+bY$ and $x=c+dX$ then the regression on x-y is $y=Ax+B$. Putting the untransformed variables back in gives
$a+bY=Ac+AdX+B$. It is then easy to see what the untransformed coefficients would be. It looks like $a=c=0$ in your case so what you suggest is correct.

Comment: Thanks! Does it change at all if there are multiple predictors?